# Как в переменную записать слово,не используя массив?

Tags: c++, строки, char

Допустим , идет поиск наибольшего числа, и имя человека с наибольшим числом очков . Его имя должно записаться в, скажем ,тип char , string . Возможна ли такая запись без  использования массива?

Comment: Ну, вот здесь `std::string name = "John Doe";` массивы не используются. А вообще, вопрос не совсем понятен. Уточните, что именно вы хотите получить. Покажите код, который уже написали.

Comment: Ну, например, вводится имя и количество очков. Имя выводится того, у кого очков больше. Вот сделать без массива это

Comment: Я кажется понял, вы хотите весь список имен хранить **не** в массиве, так? А чем вам эти массивы так не нравятся?

Comment: @eanmos В `std::string name = "John Doe";` используется аж целых два массива - один для содержимого строкового литерала, второй - динамически выделенный массив внутри `string`.

Comment: @VTT, ну, строка это по-любому массив символов (в большинстве ЯП). А «явных» массивов в моем примере нет.

Comment: @eanmos Ну с таким подходом `std::array` или `std::vector` тоже не массивы...

Comment: @VTT, для человека, не знающего C++, присутствие массивов в моем примере будет, как минимум, не очевидно. Вот что я подразумевал под «неявные массивы».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Набрасываю решение.

Берете одну переменную для имени, одну - для очков. Читаете первого в эти переменные.

Далее циклом читаете остальных - в еще *одну* переменную имени и *одну* очков. Если у нового очки больше - записываете в первые переменные имя и очки, если нет - игнорируете.

Что-то типа (считайте, псевдокод :))

```
string name, tmp_name;
int score, tmp_score;

inputStream >> name >> score;

while(inputStream >> tmp_name >> tmp_score)
{
    if (tmp_score > score)
    {
        name = tmp_name;
        score = tmp_score;
    }
}

cout << name << " " << score;
```

Примерно так.

Comment: Разве не будет считывать лишь 1 букву?

Comment: Это удивительно..

Comment: Во-первых, это *набросок*, а не живой код. Во-вторых, в `name` будет читать слово, а не букву. Если надо несколько слов - тут нужно иначе.

Comment: Кстати, как найти выход из цикла? Я смог оборвать его введя имя и число в другом порядке

Comment: Сами решайте. Ввести предопределенную строку, нажать Ctrl-Z...